# JSF error-page after PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, error-handling

I have the usual JSF error handling setup with

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

that works fine with OmniFaces' [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler).

Now when there is an error during facelet rendering (i.e. wrong property referenced - typo) the `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` is thrown and error page is being displayed but following exception is thrown

```
Mar 17, 2015 10:22:09 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/error.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:578)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:212)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:723)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:938)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:377)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:427)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:376)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:146)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As far as I understand the issue is that the rendering of original page has begun and `getOutputStream()` has been called.Now, when the error page should be rendered the `getOutputStream()` is called again and since specification says that cannot be done twice, the above exception is thrown.

Or maybe I didn't understand something ?

Of course the whole issue is caused by typo in facelet that could be validated by IDE, I am just wondering if there is a way to display error page for this types or errors.

Thanks

Comment: Which Mojarra and Tomcat version? Tried latest? Do you happen to have any servlet filters which you removed from stack trace for apparent brevity/security?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I am on Mojarra 2.1.7 & Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.0.But actually this behavior can be replicated on Tomcat7 and WebSphere7 as well.

Yeah I have some filters but these are only applied to original page, not to my error page.I can post the full stack trace if it helps...

Comment: Can you try latest Mojarra 2.1.x version? (just to exclude it being caused by a Mojarra bug; 2.1.7 is rather old too). Can you assure that those filters don't do anything with response body?

Comment: Just tried with 2.1.29-01 (which should be lastest 2.1.x) and its the same.
I see where you are going with filters but none of them touches that, even debug shows that it's all JSF calling ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter().

In general I would kind of expect this behavior as both, the original page and the error page needs to use the writer to write the HTML.

its just that the original page rendering fails so there is an attempt to render error page.

The original page hits the exception during encoding of PrimeFaces DataTable, not sure if it matters....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, the reason for this error message is usage of [Primefaces Extensions Layout](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/layout.jsf).
In this case the when rendering of the layout content fails the layout itself can't be rendered.